# Problems with shell script (sed) in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am attempting to run the following script in bash:

```
#! /bin/Bash

cp '../Text_Files_Backups/'*.txt .

sed -i '1,/Ref/d' *.txt

##Deletes all lines from the begining of file up to and including the line that includes the text 'Ref'
##      

sed -i -b '/^.$/,$d' *.txt
##Deletes all blank lines and text following and including the first blank line

sed -i 's/\([(a-zA-Z) ]\)\([(1-9)][(0-9)][ ][ ]\)/\1\n\2/g' *.txt
##Searches document for any instance of a letter character immediately followed by a 2 digit number ##immediately followed by 2 blank spaces
##  <or>
##a blank space immediately followed by a 2 digit number immediately followed by 2 blank spaces
##      and inserts a new line immediately prior to the 2 digit number

exit
```

Each line has been tested separately and functions as it should, except when put together into a script.

The first file seems to be just fine. The next 4 files are blank. Then the next 2 files are good. This keeps up at seemingly random intervals throughout the 550 files that I need to run this on.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please show us your input file and desired output

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i -b '/^.$/,$d' *.txt
##Deletes all blank lines and text following and including the first blank line
```

You probably mean

```
sed -i -b '/^$/,$d' *.txt
```

Even further

```
sed -i -b '/^[[:blank:]]*$/,$d' *.txt
```

Which would include those lines with only spaces.

On a test, this command

```
(echo a; echo b; echo; echo b; echo; echo; echo c; echo d) | sed '/^$/,$d'
```

Shows

```
a
b
```

While this command

```
(echo a; echo b; echo; echo b; echo; echo; echo c; echo d) | sed '/^.$/,$d'
```

Shows nothing.

Comment: That was my original command, but it didn't work properly. I deleted the subsequent pages in a multi-page document, but not the lines at the bottom of the first page. I was given ^.$ from another member here and to correct that issue.

Comment: @DominicRomano On my test it works as intended. Even on a file.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the line '/^$/,$d' doesn't work on my system. I need to use '/^.$/,$d' in order to get the desired results.

Comment: @DominicRomano I think that (`'/^.$/,$d'`) would actually work if your files are in CRLF format, but the proper way for that is `'/^\r$/,$d'`. Probably when you were testing `/^$/,$d` you were actually doing it on a CRLF file? Also a compatible approach is `/^\r\?$/,$d` which would apply on either formats. For including lines with only spaces, use `'/^[[:space:]]*$/,$d'`.

Comment: @DominicRomano I hope you could try at least `'/^\r\?$/,$d'` or `'/^[[:space:]]*$/,$d'` and tell us how it goes.

Comment: @konsolbox - That seems to have got me closer. There are much fewer files with nothing in them this time. You are correct, the files I have are CRLF, converted from PDF. What I am trying to do is populate an Excel file/SQL table with the contents of the PDF files, and have the needed ability to do so again in the future.